# People as a verb, what does it mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

"She **peoples** her fiction with the eccentric, comic, but vital inhabitants of rural Mississippi."

What does peoples mean in that phrase?

Comment: Synonym of "to populate"

Comment: @BenZotto is exactly right. I see you are new to this website, like me. I have learned that, here, you are encouraged to show what research you have already done when you ask a question: http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. Did you look this word up in a dictionary? What did you find? Help us to help you. Show us what research you have done and tell us why you are still having trouble. If you looked the word up and there were multiple meanings and you weren't sure which one applied - tell us. If you couldn't understand the definition - tell us. You'll get better answers that way.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/people), it means "to fill with inhabitants".