# What does it mean? "I can't people today"

Tags: phrase-meaning, slang, verbing

There is a shirt with a sentence written on it. The sentence is :

> I can't people today

What does it mean? I've seen [this link](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/58094/people-as-a-verb-what-does-it-mean) and I know that "people" can be a verb but in this special case, I don't get the meaning of the phrase.

Comment: Verbing weirds ***nouns***. As with [this question about **dust** on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/336646/2637), you just have to figure out which relationship between the subject *(**I**)* and the verbified noun *(**people**)* makes most sense in the given context. So you might have a "Provisional = provide with, add" relationship when you people an uninhabited land (***add*** people to it), or a "Privative = deprive, remove" relationship if you flea the cat (***get rid of*** the cat's fleas), for example.

Comment: Although almost any noun can become a verb and see widespread use, **people** is not yet one that has entered the language, and that is part of the humor. Not only is the person unable to deal with people today; he or she is barely able to get a sentence out.

Comment: In other words: 'I am proficient at broken English'. More specifically, this 'sentence' carries no intrinsic information that can help you sort it out. In short: that is noninformation. Being unable to 'get a simple sentence out' is not funny, but tragic -all the more so we are paying attention to it.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

It's supposed to be funny.

It implies

> I can't **deal with** people today.

I personally didn't find it funny because this structure

> I can't [noun]

seems cliche to me.

It is supposed to invoke something like this
[image]

It's akin to

> I can't even

if you are familiar with that expression.

---

I felt like I should probably note that the structure (using nouns as verbs) can change meaning. It isn't fixed. But it is usually used to be funny. For example,

> I can't math today.

It could mean I can't do/comprehend/tolerate/teach math, all depending on context.

Today, before I went to class, I saw this post. I was exhausted and I really didn't plan anything for class. So I was thinking, *I can't math today*.
In other words, I can't teach math today. (I wasn't trying to be funny; that's how I felt. But it could be used by someone else to be funny, like if they ***really*** hated math.)

---

[Here is an instance](https://youtu.be/3LQ7xB9KTrQ?t=340) of *to [noun]*. The speaker is talking about the abundance of tutorials in the game [Pokemon LeafGreen](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_FireRed_and_LeafGreen_Versions)

> You get a tutorial battle where you are told how to play Pokemon.
>   And then there is an old man later on who tells you **how to Pokemon**.

In this instance, we infer that "to Pokemon" means "to play [the game] Pokemon [LeafGreen]". He's trying to be funny/cutesy. He gets a couple of smiles, but no one really laughs out loud.

Comment: The original meme was (probably) "I can't adult today"... which is meant to be interpreted as "I can't be an adult today". Following that syntax, this would actually mean "I can't be a person today". Your interpretation certainly makes sense, too... but I don't know that's the intent.

Comment: @Catija Both this answer and the accepted answer are possible like you say. I have to side with this one because, while adult is singular, people is plural and doesn't easily translate the same way that "I can't adult" translates to "I can't be an adult." Maybe if it was "I can't person today," then  "I can't be a person today" would make more sense as a translation.

Comment: So "I can't [singular noun] today" would translate to "I can't be a [singular noun] today." And "I can't [plural noun] today" would translate to "I can't deal with [plural noun]" today.

Comment: It is slang used by teenage girls.  If a native speaker uses it, it makes them sound kind of dumb _(I'm sure your native language similarly has slang only used by teenage girls)_.  If a non-native speaker uses it, my first assumption would be they're bad at English.  It'd be best to avoid it.

Comment: Other memes that support this meaning include **I would leave my house more often if it wasn't always so people outside**. Clearly, this one has to do with dealing with other people, not being a people (sic). Also, a *I can't people today* page at [pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com/morelemonade/i-cant-people-today/) dealing with introversion.

Comment: And [another pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/553239135453068441/) with *I can't people today*, dealing with  introversion. And: **Sorry I can't; I've already filled my people quota for today**. And *Sorry  I'm not good at people-ing*. [Gifts for introverts](http://goodlifemoms.com/2015/06/12/cant-people-today/).

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft -It is not only used by teenaged girls. It is a broad internet meme used by many types of people.

Comment: @Catija true.  The key characteristic shared between all users of this formulation is that they have poor taste in speech patterns.

Answer (score 18):

This isn't normal English. The person who wrote this is deliberately using weird grammar for fun.

This is something people do as a joke: using words as verbs even though they're not verbs. People also say things like "I forgot how to American" (meaning something like: I forgot how to act like an American) or "how do I piano" (how do I use a piano). You have to kind of guess the meaning of the 'verb'. It's deliberately not very clear.
What's meant here would be something like "I can't deal with people today".

Comment: Downvoted because I am a native English speaker, and constructions like "I can't people today" sound perfectly normal to me. I hear them from other native English speakers on a regular basis, and in my experience they are more often used for ordinary communication than for jokes or wordplay.

Comment: @Vectornaut I think it _is_ a bit of a joke, but also carrying a serious meaning. It's certainly not formally correct. The fact that you only see this as negative statements is the key. It's wordplay suggesting by implication that they're so flustered by the prospect of having to "people" that they also forgot how to grammar.

Comment: @Vectornaut you need more educated people around you. That's nowhere near perfectly normal.

Comment: Educated people also indulge in wordplay.

Comment: @Vectornaut - I too am a native English speaker, but I have never heard anyone say anything like this. I think it may also depend on the country as to how prolific this is (I live in the UK).

Comment: @JDługosz I'm not a native speaker but Vectornaut's English seems perfect to me so I'm not sure how he/she might benefit from having more educated people around.

Comment: @Vectornaut Maybe your downvote is a bit harsh - I'm a native English speaker in England, and these kind of sentences _really_ jar for me - if I saw someone wearing a tshirt saying "I can't people today" it would probably cause me to unconsciously curl my lip in disgust.

Comment: @stripybadger, that's exactly why I downvoted: I think it's very misleading to say without qualification that something "isn't normal English" when normal speech from one region can make speakers from another region recoil in disgust.

Comment: @MattWilko, I'd guess this sort of construction is restricted to a very small community of speakers. I'm tempted to suggest, glibly, that it's regional to certain parts of Tumblr. (If you want to get a real picture of where it can be found, the Know Your Meme link in KutuluMike's answer might be a good place to start.)

Comment: @SantiBailors, I'm glad you like my English! I think one of the chief benefits of a classical education is being able to garner respect from authority figures by talking like *The New York Times*.

Answer (score 11):

The phrase is a strange and ungrammatical way to say "I don't want to have to do the things that people do every day, because I can't handle it."

This is an example of a relatively popular meme, all of which are variations on the so-called ["Adulting"](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/adulting) meme. The syntax of the phrase is deliberately bad English, which is intended to inject humor into the saying. But if you're not already very familiar with the *intended* meaning, the literal meaning just sounds wrong.

The original phrase, which your example is a derivative of, was "I can't adult today, please don't make me adult". The relies on the use of the noun "adult" as if it were a verb, and probably derives from the "[adultingblog](http://adultingblog.com/)" Tumblr account. (Warning some NSFW language in some of the posts.) The blog author used the term "adulting" to mean "the process of being, or acting like, an adult", as if it were a job title. If we expand this concept to your example, we can see the pattern:

- to survey -> activity that defines one as a surveyor
- to bake -> activity that defines one as a baker
- to adult -> activity that defines one as an adult
- to people -> activity that defines one as a person

Note also the deliberate use of the plural "people" even though the speaker is a single person, again relying on improper grammar to inject humor.

Comment: A good answer but I think the phrase in question is referring to socializing: "I don't want to have to deal with people today".

Comment: It's possible, but that's not usual meaning of the meme. "I can't adult today" doesn't mean "I don't want to deal with adults", it means "I don't want to *be* an adult". Similar with the other variants...

Comment: @KutuluMike I've only ever heard of "not being able to people" as "not being able to deal with people and their stuff", definitely not the same as "not being able to adult"

Comment: @BrianLeishman The question is about _"I can't people today"_, not _"Not being able to people"_.

Comment: @pipe If I can't people then I'm also lacking the ability to people, I'm failing to see the distinction

Comment: @BrianLeishman If you want to argue with someone on the internet, it's better for everyone if you both argue about the same thing.

Comment: I don't think "to bake" is an activity that defines one as a baker. It is an activity that a baker does. "to adult" is to do activities adults do. I think that you've overlooked that it's "I can't people today" and not "I can't person today". I read it as "[I can't "do" people today](http://www.ellenryanbrand.com/#!product-page/cm5q/7a6e3962-5b85-195f-3ea6-55527e88140e)" not "I can't be a person today".

Comment: @KutuluMike it's a variant on a saying, sure, but that doesn't necessarily mean it has the same kind of meaning. you're being misled by the similar construction. i've seen it used both ways: either meaning you aren't a person or you don't want to deal with people.

Comment: Like JamieB, Brian Leishman, and ColleenV, I read "I can't people" and "unable to people" as "I can't [deal with] people" and "unable to [deal with] people," respectively. Like ColleenV, I'd probably read "I can't person" as "I can't [be a] person," although I don't recall hearing "I can't person" in conversation.

Comment: Agreed, this means "I can't deal with people today;" it has a different meaning than "I can't adult today," which means "I can't deal with being an adult today."

Comment: I recognize that many of you disagree with me, which is fine. It's not necessary for every one of you to leave me the exact same comment -- if you find my answer incomplete or incorrect, you are strongly encouraged to write your own better one...

Comment: @KutuluMike If you stand by this definition, then can you present any quotes or references of "to people" being used to mean "to do that which defines a person"? Good answers are supported with evidence :)

Comment: @KutuluMike, when there's doubt about how widespread a certain usage of a phrase is, I think it's good for lots of people to drop by and say whether they're familiar with it. That's why I left my comment, and it may be the reason other people are commenting as well. The fact that we're all leaving the *same* comment suggests that the usage we're familiar with may be much more common than the one you describe, although of course one can't draw any real conclusions from such a small and self-selected sample.